# Trouble passing a whole structure array to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, structure

I'm sort of new to C++ and programming in general. I'm making a pokemon remake of the old gameboy version for fun, and I'm having trouble passing a whole structure as an arguement.

This is a shortened version to highlight the problem I'm having:

```
struct Enemy_Pokeman
{
    string opp_name;
    int num_pokeman;
    int pokeman_LVL;                  
};   

void pl_Pokeman(Enemy_Pokeman); 

void pokeman_data(string opp_name, int num_pokeman, int pokeman_ID[], int pokeman_LVL[],
                  int purpose)
{
    Enemy_Pokeman enemypokeman[num_pokeman];

    enemypokeman[0].opp_name = opp_name;
    enemypokeman[0].num_pokeman = num_pokeman;
    for(int i=0; i<num_pokeman; i++)
        enemypokeman[i].pokeman_LVL = pokeman_LVL[i];

    pl_Pokeman(enemypokeman);                   //Function call - Codeblocks detects error
                                            //on this line
}

void pl_Pokeman(Enemy_Pokeman enemy)        
{
    cout << endl;
}
```

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I didn't want to post the entire thing, so I chopped it up a bit.
The problem is that it won't accept `Enemy_Pokeman` as an arguement.

Answer (score 1):

Function `pl_Pokeman` only takes `Enemy_Pokeman` type while you passed in `an array of Enemy_Pokeman`

You update `pl_Pokeman function` to take array as input:

```
void pl_Pokeman(Enemy_Pokeman enemy[], int arraySize);
```

Or

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void pl_Pokeman(Enemy_Pokeman (&enemy)[N])
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I tried this while I was testing different options, but must have overlooked it. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

For Single structure-

When you are passing the structure as a argument, you should pass with `&` operator.

```
pl_Pokeman(&enemypokeman); // Fix 1
```

While catching it you need to catch it with Structure pointer.

```
void pl_Pokeman(Enemy_Pokeman *); // Fix 2
```

For Array of structure-

```
pl_Pokeman(&enemypokeman,size); // pass it with size
```

while catching it

```
void pl_Pokeman(Enemy_Pokeman (*)[], int );
```

Answer (score 0):

you're passing to your function whole array of `Enemy_Pokeman`s, not just one element. function expects one element only. also, you're creating that array within a function, so it's a local variable. if function `pokemon_data` returns, that array will be destroyed.